# PHP pattern to add, edit, view and delete database entry

Tags: php, database, design-patterns, view, edit

I would like to create a PHP class to contain some kind of data (an article with a "title" and a "text"). This class should be used for different purposes:

- *create a new entry* : show a form with empty "title" and "text"
  input fields and a submit button to add data to database (after
  validation)
- *edit an existing entry* (passing ID to constructor): show a
  form with "title" and "text" input fields filled with data retrieved
  from DB and a submit button to add data to database (after
  validation)
- *view an existing entry* (passing ID to constructor): show
  non-editable "title" and "text" fields (i.e. "h1" and "p") filled
  with data retrieved from DB
- *delete an existing entry* (passing ID to constructor): show
  non-editable "title" and "text" fields (i.e. "h1" and "p") filled
  with data retrieved from DB and a submit button to delete data from
  database

It should be a very common situation, but I haven't found any design pattern to perform it. 
Do you have any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: CRUD, Data table gateway, Data row gateway, Active record, there's plenty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most PHP MVC's contain good design patterns for these kind of problems. Check out frameworks like:

- Laravel: [laravel.com](http://laravel.com/)
- CakePHP: [cakephp.org](http://cakephp.org/)
- Zend Framework: [framework.zend.com](http://framework.zend.com/)

If you want to keep it simple and just design a single PHP class for this problem, you should check out CRUD, ORM and ActiveRecord. The following link might come in handy: [PHP ActiveRecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Basic_CRUD)

Answer (score 1):

#### You're actually looking for a [DataMapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mapper_pattern).

Since all those CRUD "operations", belong to the same responsibility (they do abstract table access), there's no need to implement separated class for each operation. You'd implement a method that abstracts single operation, that related to a table you're working with. You can do this, like:

```
class ArticleMapper
{
     protected $pdo;

     protected $table = 'some_table';

     public function __construct(PDO $pdo)
     {
         $this->pdo = $pdo;
     }

     /**
      * @return boolean Depending on success
      */
     public function insert($id, $title, $text)
     {
         $query = sprintf('INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `title`, `text`) VALUES (:id, :title, :text)', $this->table);
         $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
         return $stmt->execute(array(
           ':title' => $title,
           ':text'  => $text,
           ':id'    => $id,
         ));
     }


     public function fetchById($id)
     {
        $query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM `%s` WHERE `id` =:id');
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array(
           ':id' => $id
        ));
        return $stmt->fetch();
     }

     // ... The rest for deleteById() and updateById()
}
```

### Benefits?

Well, if they aren't obvious, it would make sense to listen them:

- Separation of application logic from its storage logic.

That means your application logic (that performs some computations), would be completely unaware of where a data is coming from. This makes your easy to maintain and to test. That adheres to the Single-Responsibility Principle

- Its fast

While ORM's, ActiveRecords, Query Builders do require additional memory (by the way, for each HTTP request, and also just look, at their classes - they are usually so large), DataMappers don't. You would only write code for the database vendor you're going to work with.

- Its easy to switch from one database vendor to another

For example, let's assume, that you're not sure now, whether you're going to switch to another database vendor in future. When working with DataMappers, all you have to do is to inject an instance of it to the classes that need it.

```
class Foo
{
    public function __construct(MapperInterface $mapper)
    {
       $this->mapper = $mapper;
    }

    public function doSomeComputationsWithId($id)
    {
        $data = $this->mapper->fetchById($id);
        // .. do computations here
        return $result;
    }
}

$mapper = new Article_MySQL_Mapper($pdo);

// or

$mapper = new Article_MongoDB_Mapper($mongoInstance);

$foo = new Foo($mapper);

print_r($foo->doSomeComputationsWithId($_GET['id']));
```